# Power-BI/DAX Cummulate Count-Value

Tags: plot, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a for me very basic question, however I don't get it to work properly.
I have a report from a ticket system. This report states in each row the date when a ticket was created and the date when this one is resolved.

My aim is to provide the following look:

- How many tickets are created in a week (eg. CW20)
- How many tickets are solved in this week

So in Power-BI I try co make the sum and then cumulate it over time:

```
CumSum_CreatedTickets = 
CALCULATE(
COUNTA('5_Michael_Report'[id]),
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('5_Michael_Report'[CW]),
ISONORAFTER('5_Michael_Report'[CW], MAX('5_Michael_Report'[CW]), DESC)
))
```

This is creating me a line which shows me how many tickets were created in a Calendar Week:

[image]

However, when I now want to plot ho many tickets are resolved in this specific week i do not get any cumulative line (see the darker grey line in the picture). I try using this formula:

```
CumSum_WeekClosed = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('5_Michael_Report'[id]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('5_Michael_Report'[Week_Closed]),
        ISONORAFTER('5_Michael_Report'[Week_Closed], MAX('5_Michael_Report'[CW]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Can anyone spot where my misunderstanding is?

## Remark:

- CW == Nubmer of Calender Week when ticket created, eg.: 30
- Week_Closed == Number of Calender_Week when ticket closed, eg.: 33

Comment: This is logic because there are always being tickets created, you are actuality counting the rows in your table. For the closed ones this is not the case because you look only at closed. If you want this to work, you will need to create a column which checks based on status if it needs to add or subtract by one, this means you need also the history of the data (what is most likely in same table).